# How to combine multiple rules?

Tags: rule

I have 2 rules:

```
Rule[#, SomeFunction[#]] &/@ SomeFunctionArgs;
Rule[#, OtherFunction[#]] &/@ OtherFunctionArgs;
```

I want to have one function that combines the 2 results in 1. I have tried to do:

```
MainFunction[] =: ( Rule[#, SomeFunction[#]] &/@ SomeFunctionArgs; Rule[#, OtherFunction[#]] &/@ OtherFunctionArgs)
```

But this didn't work.

Any advices?

UPDADE:

```
SomeFunctionArgs = {
    "A",
    "B"
}

OtherFunctionArgs = { 
    "C",
    "D"
}
```

This will give `{A -> "result1", B -> "result2"}`

```
Rule[#, SomeFunction[#]] &/@ SomeFunctionArgs
```

This will give `{C -> "result3", D -> "result4"}`

```
Rule[#, OtherFunction[#]] &/@ OtherFunctionArgs
```

I want `MainFunction[]` to give the following result:

`{A -> "result1", B -> "result2", C -> "result3", D -> "result4"}`

Comment: Why not simply use `Join`?

Comment: Are you just seeking to apply a function to specific set of arguments as you would using the Map[] function ? Or is your goal something different ? Perhaps some input and output examples might make this more evident.

Comment: Please see the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
Join[
Rule[#, SomeFunction[#]] &/@ SomeFunctionArgs,
Rule[#, OtherFunction[#]] &/@ OtherFunctionArgs
]
```

This does the required. I was failing, as I was using `;` instead of `,`.

@ David Carraher  Thanks for the comment.